# PHP Simplexml traversal

Tags: php, simplexml

I am trying to traverse this xml feed:

```
http://www.goonersworld.co.uk/forum/feed.php
```

using this code:

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://www.goonersworld.co.uk/forum/feed.php');
                //$data = str_replace("content:encoded>","content>",$data);
                $xml = simplexml_load_string($data,'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);

                foreach ($xml->feed->entry as $stories) {

                     echo $stories->published."<br>";
                }
```

But I'm getting nothing back.   To me it looks like $xml->feed->entry->published but am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've figured this out.  In case it helps anyone else it was a feed generated by PHPBB (Bulletin Board).

The actual structure I was looking for was simply:

```
 foreach ($xml->entry as $stories) {

                 echo $stories->published."<br>";
            }
```

feed and entry didn't look to be at the same level in the XML formatting but they were :-(

Comment: The key is not that `<feed>` and `<entry>` are at the same level, it's that the variable `$xml` represents the XML node `<feed>` (the root node of the document), so `$xml->feed->entry` would need an XML looking like `<feed><feed><entry>...` (or `<somethingelse><feed><entry>...`)